# Why is this MySQL query taking so long?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm looking to do a relatively simply filter from one table called **prices**.

**prices** is a very large table (~2G records).  Sample data, query and indexes included below.  I realize the table being queried is very large, but for a query this simple I would have expected better performance (currently ~5 mins and running).  I did notice InnoDB Buffer Usage appears to be at 100% per MySQL Workbench, with ~6K InnoDB reads per second.  Guidance on adjustments to make to correct this.

**prices**

```
dataDate     ticker  optionSymbol    expDate     type    price   strike  last    bid     ask     volume  OI
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00005000 2002-02-16   call   24.03   5   0   18.8    19.1    0   0
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216P00005000 2002-02-16   put    24.03   5   0   0   0.05    0   0
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00007500 2002-02-16   call   24.03   7.5 0   16.3    16.6    0   0
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216P00007500 2002-02-16   put    24.03   7.5 0   0   0.05    0   0
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00010000 2002-02-16   call   24.03   10  12.2    13.9    14.2    0   1
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216P00010000 2002-02-16   put    24.03   10  0   0   0.05    0   0
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00012500 2002-02-16   call   24.03   12.5    13.5    11.4    11.7    0   8
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216P00012500 2002-02-16   put    24.03   12.5    0.05    0   0.05    0   50
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00015000 2002-02-16   call   24.03   15  7.1 8.9 9.1 0   10
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216P00015000 2002-02-16   put    24.03   15  0.1 0   0.05    0   30
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00017500 2002-02-16   call   24.03   17.5    5.5 6.4 6.7 0   371
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216P00017500 2002-02-16   put    24.03   17.5    0.05    0   0.05    0   147
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00020000 2002-02-16   call   24.03   20  3.9 3.9 4.1 7   1064
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216P00020000 2002-02-16   put    24.03   20  0.1 0   0.1 5   1448
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00022500 2002-02-16   call   24.03   22.5    1.7 1.7 1.75    1551    7069
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216P00022500 2002-02-16   put    24.03   22.5    0.2 0.15    0.25    136 3234
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00025000 2002-02-16   call   24.03   25  0.3 0.1 0.35    105 4237
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216P00025000 2002-02-16   put    24.03   25  1.25    1.2 1.35    629 589
2002-02-08   AAPL    AAQ020216C00027500 2002-02-16   call   24.03   27.5    0.05    0   0.1 0   1097
```

**Query**

```
select *
from op.prices op
where ticker = 'AAPL'
and '2020-04-30' between date_add(expDate, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and expDate
and '2020-04-30' = date_add(op.dataDate, INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

**Indexes**
[image]

Comment: What happens when you change the `WHERE` statement to just `dataDate = '2020-04-16' AND ticker = 'AAPL'`

Comment: @bbaird, it completed almost instantaneously.  You know something about `date_add` that I don't?

Comment: Incidentally, I don't really see that this is a dba question. This is a straight-up mysql question, and belongs in Stack Overflow

Comment: incidentally, are there indices made on the relevant fields?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Instead of

```
'2020-04-30' = date_add(op.dataDate, INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

Use

```
op.dataDate = date_sub('2020-04-30', INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

Your first statement will be interpreted as "add 14 days to all `dataDate` and return when that is 2020-04-30."  This will require a full scan of the table.

The second statement will evaluate to: "return records where the `dataDate` is 2020-04-16."  This allows the engine to perform a seek on your index that begins with `dataDate`.

Do whatever weird stuff you want to do to `expDate` since that won't factor much into how the query engine will optimize.

Comment: clever, and in hindsight completely right.  Any sense for why the `between` clause isn't similarly impacted?

Comment: On the index utilized, `expDate` is behind `dataDate` and `Ticker`.  With the modification the query can search on `dataDate` and `Ticker` and whatever is left over doesn't really matter at that point because you're not dealing with as many rows.

Comment: It's called SARGS.

Answer (score 6):

The formulation is the main problem.  After rewriting the query, the index you have can be used for the entire `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  op.prices
    WHERE  ticker = 'AAPL'
      AND expDate >= '2020-04-30'
      AND expDate  < '2020-04-30' + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
      AND dataDate = '2020-04-30' - INTERVAL 14 DAY
```

See Sargeable in Wikipedia.  Phrased differently "Don't hide a column in a function call -- it may not be usable by an index."

Shrinking the file size will help some:

- Consider switching from 8-byte `DOUBLE` (about 16 significant digits) to 4-byte `FLOAT` (about 7 significant digits) for the metrics.
- A 1-byte `ENUM('put','call')` would save 3 bytes per row.
- Normalizing the Option (a long string).

There may be more tips.  To see how important shrinking is, answer these:  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How big (GB) is the table?

You really should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Devil's advocate, but why should I really have a `PRIMARY KEY`?  In this case, the first index (date, ticker, expDate, type) is really the closest thing to a key.

Comment: "Index" and "key" mean effectively the same thing in MySQL.  The one and only `PRIMARY KEY` for a table identifies each row uniquely.  It is a unique and it is an index.  The PK is "clustered" with the data, providing an order for the data.

Comment: Do you have any other secondary indexes?  Is that combo of 4 columns unique.  Probably the best order would be (ticker, type, datadate, expdate).  But it depends on what other important queries touch this table.